# Reference request: A real analysis textbook complementary to Stein's with examples

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I have real analysis this semester, and the reference is Stein. Is it only me, or is Stein's textbook actually very compressed and hard to digest/decipher? It provides too few examples.

I need a complementary textbook on real analysis that explains the concepts easier and with MANY EXAMPLES.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which textbook of Stein? The four-volume thing?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, volume III.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a book with lots of examples and that is aimed at preparing undergraduate students for a graduate level textbook, I would recommend Gail S. Nelson's ["A User-Friendly Introduction to Lebesgue Measure and Integration"](https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=3fjkCgAAQBAJ).

I think this book would definitely serve as the complementary textbook that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend Zygmund's book: Measure and Integral.

Also you can take a look at Royden's book :Real analysis.

And the book of G De Barra:Measure and integration.

Also another good book with examples is V.Bogachev: measure theory.

Comment: I looked them up, and they too don't provide examples?

Comment: @Asmani i proposed two more book..check, if some of this books helps you.

Comment: They look great, thanks!